# How can I hide some indicator icons?

Tags: wingpanel

I don't need all of the default shown indicator icons.

[image: Indicator icons]

How can I hide some of them, such as the icon for Geary email client (shown by the bell)?

Comment: how did you get Google Drive working on elementary?

Comment: @jena [Insync](https://www.insynchq.com/).

Comment: oh I see, cool..

Comment: How i can reinstall the indicator powerw icon?
(I use "sudo apt-get remove indicator-power" to remove it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, first of all, that's not a Geary indicator, that's `indicator-messages` and it has a lot more functionality than just displaying Geary notifications.

To delete it completely from your system, you can execute this command:

```
sudo apt-get remove indicator-messages
```

After it, all you need to do is to re-login (I have just tested this and it works).

Names of other default indicators:

- `indicator-power` (the battery icon)
- `indicator-bluetooth` (the Bluetooth icon)
- `indicator-datetime` (date and time indicator in the center of Wingpanel)
- `indicator-sound` (self-explanatory)
- `network-manager-gnome` (network icon)

Alternatively, if you just want to disable their startup but not remove them from the system, you could try to go to `/etc/xdg/autostart` and delete their `.desktop` files (note: I haven't tested this method).

Answer (score 0):

On Loki, you can change the visibility of various indicators in the wingpanel using dconf.

```
sudo apt install dconf-tools
```

Open dconf Editor and disable the indicators by going to `org.pantheon.desktop.wingpanel.indicators.<indicator_name>` and changing the boolean value to false.

Comment: Turns out this doesn't actually work, but it prevents bluetooth from turning back on after restarting.